# TouchID "On" vs "On but suspended"

Tags: ios, touch-id

Is there a way to determine if there is a fingerprint registered but Touch ID is currently in a "suspended" state because of too many failed fingerprint authentications?

Comment: I don't see how this question is "Too broad". It is quite clear and asks for a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error codes can be compared to the LAError class.

```
func errorMessageForLAErrorCode( errorCode:Int ) -> String{

        var message = ""

        switch errorCode {

        case LAError.AppCancel.rawValue:
            message = "Authentication was cancelled by application"

        case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.rawValue:
            message = "The user failed to provide valid credentials"

        case LAError.InvalidContext.rawValue:
            message = "The context is invalid"

        case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue:
            message = "Passcode is not set on the device"

        case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
            message = "Authentication was cancelled by the system"

        case LAError.TouchIDLockout.rawValue:
            message = "Too many failed attempts."

        case LAError.TouchIDNotAvailable.rawValue:
            message = "TouchID is not available on the device"

        case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
            message = "The user did cancel"

        case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:
            message = "The user chose to use the fallback"

        default:
            message = "Did not find error code on LAError object"

        }

        return message

    }
```

Comment: In Objective C, the specific case required here is `LAErrorTouchIDLockout `.